# Integer solutions to $ax+by -cz = 0$ in relation to Pythagorean triples.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

In a paper by Frink (1987), it was shown that if $(x,y,z)$ are solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2 = z^2 +1$ and $(a,b,c)$ are primitive Pythagorean triples i.e, solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ (pairwise relatively prime), then:

$$(x,y,z) = (x+a, y+ b, z+c) \\ 
(x', y',z') = (x'+ a, y'+b, z'+c) $$

where $x+ x' = a, y+y' = b, \mbox{and }  z+z' =c$ are pairs of solutions to $x^2+y^2 = z^2 +1$.

I tried to prove this algebraically by showing that:

\begin{aligned}
&(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2 - (z+c)^2 = 1 \\ 
&(x^2 + y^2 -z^2) + (a^2+b^2-c^2)  + 2(ax+by-cz) = 1 \\
&\implies 2(ax+by-cz) = 0 
\end{aligned}

I've tried to verify this for some $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ and the last equation does hold. However, I am not certain if this holds **in general**.

My question is how do I show that $(ax+by-cz) = 0$ given the properties provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is that if $x^2+ y^2 = z^2 + 1$
and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then $a x + b y = cz$ if and only if
$(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2 = (z+c)^2 + 1$.
This is simply from the fact that
$$(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2 - (z+c)^2 = (x^2 + y^2 - z^2) + 2 (a x + by - cz) + (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)$$

Comment: Is there a way to algebraically show that $ax+ by = cz = 0$ given that $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple and $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x^2 + y^2 = z^2 +1$?

Comment: No, because it's not true. Counterexamples are easy to find.